# Report Tool With Designer - Java Web Application

Tags: java

I want to integrate reports in java web application. The reporting design should be done by the open source report designer by me or the customer on their end and use it in the application.

When i search for reports, come across the following with respect to java

```
Birt
Jtidy
Apache FOP
Jasper
Spring PDF
Docmosis
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The two options which at least I know or used so far, one is Jasper reports where iReport is used as designer and the other one is Birt.

Jasper reports can be used in web applications as well as Desktop application and reports can be easily designed in iReport which is Open source.